# Django serializer not showing child model fields

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am having an issue with my serializer not returning the fields from a child model when using the model serializer inside another serializer (foreign key relation). I am not looking for a solution to this, but rather why it is not working.

models.py

```
class LinkedinAccount(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_prospect = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class LinkedinProspectAccount(LinkedinAccount):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class LinkedinAccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = user_account.models.LinkedinAccount
        fields = ('id', 'name')
        read_only_fields = ('date_created',)


class LinkedinProspectAccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = user_account.models.LinkedinProspectAccount
        fields = ('title', 'company', 'country', 'city')
        read_only_fields = ('date_created',)


class ConversationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    linkedin_account = user_account.serializers.LinkedinAccountSerializer()
    last_message = MessageSerializer()
    prospect = user_account.serializers.LinkedinProspectAccountSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = conversation.models.Conversation
        fields = ('id', 'linkedin_account', 'prospect', 'conversation_id', 'archived',
                  'last_message')
        lookup_field = None

    read_only_fields = ('created_at', 'updated_at',)
```

What I am getting back from a normal GET request using generics.ListCreateAPIView is:

> [OrderedDict([('id', 1), ('linkedin_account', OrderedDict([('id', 1),
>   ('name', 'Test LinkedIn account')])), ('prospect', OrderedDict()),
>   ('conversation_id', '100'), ('archived', False), ('last_message',
>   None)])]

The prospect object has no fields, if I add the base model fields in the serializer they are returned, but still none of the child model fields. When using the LinkedinProspectAccountSerializer on its own it works fine. Currently I am using this as a workaround:

```
def get_prospect(self, obj):
    prospect = user_account.models.LinkedinProspectAccount.objects.get(id=obj.prospect.id)
    serializer = user_account.serializers.LinkedinProspectAccountSerializer(prospect)
    return serializer.data
```

Comment: I think you need to add ForeignKey to LinkedinProspectAccount as it's shown here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#api-reference Since your two relations are not connected, it's not showing nested relations/values. Please give it try!

Comment: @AshutoshKS I already have them related by LinkedinProspectAccount model inheriting LinkedinAccount, the foreign key relation would be redundant.